# Validate strange characters

Tags: php, wordpress, character

I' am getting the following characters on my website contact us form. How can I validate the message field so that such characters are not allowed.

```
Ð”Ð¾Ð±Ñ€Ñ‹Ð¹ Ð´ÐµÐ½ÑŒ! ÐžÐºÐ°Ð·Ñ‹Ð²Ð°ÐµÐ¼ Ð¿Ð¾Ð¼Ð¾Ñ‰ÑŒ Ð² Ð¿Ð¾Ð»ÑƒÑ‡ÐµÐ½Ð¸Ð¸ Ð³Ñ€Ð°Ð¶Ð´Ð°Ð½Ð°Ð¼ Ð¸ ÑÐ¾Ñ‚Ñ€ÑƒÐ´Ð½Ð¸ÐºÐ°Ð¼ Ñ„Ð¸Ñ€Ð¼ ÐºÐ°Ñ€Ñ‚Ð¾Ñ‡ÐµÐº Ð¼ÐµÑ‚Ñ€Ð¾ Ð² ÑÐµÑ‚ÑŒ Ð½ÐµÐ¼ÐµÑ†ÐºÐ¸Ñ…
```

**This is the code am currently using**

```
$message = sanitize_text_field($message);
$message = str_replace("`","", $message);
```

Comment: I hope you are doing some kind of conditional validation. Here is an example  `$message = 'This is my test message. I hope you are happy now!'; if( !preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\/\-.,;\'" ]+$/', $message)){$msg = 'The message field contains invalid characters.';}`. This will help you in telling the user that there are some strange characters in the message field.

Comment: Thanks @NavneilNaicker It works great.

Comment: Take a look here for examples using filter_var(). https://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Filtering-Data-with-PHP.html#12